# Would the two following examples take up equal memory after compiling?

Tags: c, memory, struct, compilation, int

Please help me with this concept:

Which would take up more memory after compiling if both are declared and initialized?

```
struct V
{
    int a, b;
};

struct X
{
    struct V v;
    int N;
};
```

**OR:**

```
struct X 
{
    int a, b, c;
};
```

Comment: Since all the structure elements are `int` with regard to memory being allocated for both structures will be same..

Comment: Note that it's easy to ask your compiler this question too: `printf("struct X1: %zu struct X2: %zu\n", sizeof(struct X1), sizeof(struct X2));`

Comment: @nos - yes but the compiler can't also explain why, or give a quick runthrough on struct padding. Not unless I code for it to... In which case I wouldn't need to ask now would I? mind... (*exploding sound*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules for structure padding:

- Padding is only inserted when a structure member is followed by a member with a larger alignment requirement or at the end of the structure.
- The last member is padded with the number of bytes required so that the total size of the structure should be a multiple of the largest alignment of any structure member.

This suggests that both will take same memory space, 12-bytes each assuming size of `int` is `4` bytes. The reason is that there is no padding in either case.

Comment: Surely you mean 12 bytes?

Comment: @haccks - I thought if you increment an int pointer it is 4 bytes?

Comment: An `int` is of 4 bytes on your machine, 3 `int` will be of `3*4` = `12` bytes.

Answer (score 2):

My common sense says me that in both cases the program will allocate the same amount of memory (3 integers).

In the end the C structs are not more than a way to help the developer to organize variables and make code more readable. Once compiled the program doesn't care about structs or code organization but about variables (memory) and operations (instructions).

Answer (score 0):

Both variants of struct X take up the same amount of memory, after all, they only contain three integers and the nested struct doesn't affect the memory layout of its member data when it comes to size.

The struct in this case is only syntactic sugar to arrange its members in a specific order and doesn't introduce additional overhead.

If there is no additional padding between the ints, both structs will consume 3 * sizeof(int) bytes.

Comment: @AndrewGrant: That's simply not true. The memory would be allocated and the values would have an __unspecified__ value.